# Formula for nearest prime $p_x$ less than a number $k$

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

In my attempts to get around Brocard's problem, I've come up with the following formula for the prime factorization of $k!$:
$$\prod_{n=1}^x\left(\prod_{s=1}^{\lfloor\log_{p_n}k\rfloor}\left(p_n^{\lfloor\frac{k}{p_n^s}\rfloor}\right)\right).$$
My problem: $x$ needs to be the greatest value for which $\frac{k}{p_x}$ is greater than or equal to $1$.  I'm currently too busy to think about it, so: does anyone know of a formula to find $x$?

Comment: Yes $p_{\pi(k)}$, since $p_{\pi(k)} \leq k<p_{\pi(k)+1}$ ... if you find a better one, let us now :)

Comment: I found $\sum_{n=2}^k\lfloor\frac{2}{\sigma_0\left(n\right)}\rfloor$ for $k\geq2$, but it feels impractical for this situation.